# how to get string[] of Map<String , string >

Tags: java

Hi i have a `Map<Str1,Str2>` and i need to get the array of str2 where

```
str1=="foo"
```

how can i do that?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `java.util.Map` is not a multi-map, then the entry having "foo" as a key, if it exists, it's unique. So I don't see why you should get a `String[]`.

Just do: `String str2 = map.get("foo")` and always check if `str2 != null` before referring to it later.

If you are interested in a multi-map (many entries for a key), then search [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) for it, or you can implement a multi-map yourself very easily, mapping any `String` key to a `Collection` of `String`s.  It's easy and it works. Choose the right `Collection` depending on how much frequently it is changed, if you need it sorted, etc... Often a `LinkedList` is fairly good.